# AWS lambda layer call says opt/ffmpeg is not a directory

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I followed this tutorial for making ffmpeg a lambda layer https://www.serverless.com/blog/publish-aws-lambda-layers-serverless-framework

I ran ls in my directory with spawnsync and the opt directory was empty and so ffmpeg didn't fire.

Any pointers on what I might be doing wrong?

I'm using node.js12.x as my runtime with the serverless framework.

Answer (score 0):

if you add

```
spawnSync( 'ls', ["/opt"], { stdio: "inherit" });
```

in your lambda code, you may see that ffmpeg execute file is directly under /opt.
it depends on how you zipped the ffmpeg folder. With the command above you could see the /opt folder structure to know with which path to call ffmpeg exe.

```
spawnSync(
  '/opt/ffmpeg',
  [
    '-i',
    `/tmp/${inputFileName}`,
    "-f",
    "gif",
    `/tmp/${outputFileName}`
  ],
  { stdio: "inherit" }
);
```

It works for me.